# Vue.js filter a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. I'm trying to display a filtered list based on the value of another object. The `select` sets the value of the object called `activeSet`. That value is the key in the `sets` object. If that keys value is greater than 0 I want to display it in the list and sort by it. Here is my code:

**JS**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeSet: 'all',
    computed: {
      activeContents: songs.filter(function(song) {
        return (song[activeSet] > 0);
      })
    },
    songs: {
      a: {
        title: 'Hound Dog',
        all: 0,
        set1: 2
      },
      b: {
        title: 'Long Gone',
        all: 1,
        set1: 0
      },
      b: {
        title: 'Novermber Rain',
        all: 2,
        set1: 3
      }
    },
    sets: {
      all: {
        name: 'All Songs'
      },
      set1: {
        name: 'Acoustic'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="activeSet">
    <option v-for="(set,key) in sets" :value="key">{{set.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li v-for="(song,key) in activeContents" :id="key" :is-active="song.show" :key="key" @click="activeSong=key">{{ song.title }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**
[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe0hd10b/3/)

Sidenote: If the value is above 0 it needs to be included and then sorted by that value. I haven't even dived into sorting yet so bonus points if you can sort by the value of those that are greater than 0.

Comment: 1) computed properties are defined as a function 2) computed properties are not defined in the `data` method 3) You need to reference the vue instance when access data properties (e.g. `this.songs`) 4) `songs` is not an array so it doesn't have a `filter` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties are not defined in `data`, they have their own section in the Vue definition. Additionally, you should use `this` to reference data properties inside the computed.

If I understand the question correctly, this should work for sorting and filtering.

```js
console.clear()
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeSet: 'all',

    songs: {
      a: {
        title: 'Hound Dog',
        all: 0,
        set1: 2
      },
      b: {
        title: 'Long Gone',
        all: 3,
        set1: 0
      },
      c: {
        title: 'Novermber Rain',
        all: 2,
        set1: 3
      }
    },
    sets: {
      all: {
        name: 'All Songs'
      },
      set1: {
        name: 'Acoustic'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
      activeContents(){
        // setup
        let set = this.activeSet
        let filter = k => this.songs[k][set] > 0
        let sorter = (a,b) => this.songs[a][set] - this.songs[b][set]
        
        // filter and sort
        let selectedKeys = Object.keys(this.songs)
          .filter(filter)
          .sort(sorter)
        
        // build new object
        return selectedKeys.reduce((acc, k) => {
          acc[k] = this.songs[k]
          return acc
         }, {})
      }
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="activeSet">
    <option v-for="(set,key) in sets" :value="key">{{set.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li v-for="(song,key) in activeContents" :id="key" :is-active="song.show" :key="key" @click="activeSong=key">{{ song.title }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bert. I did end up with one issue. The Object we filter get's returned as an array with numerical keys instead of the Object that we start with. Other parts of the program relies on the keys a,b,c, etc. Is there any way to return the `songs` Object just as it was to begin with (as an object) but just filtered? On a side note, I do have lodash installed on the actual project. Not sure if that would help or not. Been fighting with this for days so thanks for your help.

Comment: @TripleC Updated the answer with what I understand to be your requirement. Let me know if you have questions.